# MacOS - Where is Terminal themes/profiles utilized by Terminal.app on disk?

Tags: macos, terminal, mojave, bash, themes

I know i can export a profile, i can then use it, but if I modify it, i have to export it again, to have a proper backup.

I'd rather have a **symlink** to the **actual** **file** in use by terminal rather than an exported version of it I have to constantly re-export when i wish to backup my system.

However, I can not find the **location** where **Terminal** uses the imported themes. Where does it put them?

Anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The properties of themes and profiles are stored in ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist in the key *Windows Settings/[Name of the Profile]*:

[image]

Obviously only diffs to a hidden default profile (it's not the Basic profile!) are stored.

In the example above I made a copy *Basic 1* of the *Basic* theme and arbitrarly disabled and enabled settings in the various tabs.

---

The initial settings for the various default profiles (*Basic*, *Man Page*, *Ocean* etc.) are stored in the app itself:

*/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/Resources/Initial Settings/*

The *.terminal files are basically XML-files. They are imported into the ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist as sub-items on the first launch of Terminal.app.

Comment: So, are you able to point to a separate cloned profile on disk? If you import a profile, where does it end up?

Comment: @momomo 1. No, you can't use a separate cloned profile - the user profiles (default or custom) are all part of the plist. 2. In the $USER plist.

Comment: but you can import a profile. does it go into the plist then ?

Comment: @momomo Yes, like the (10?) default profiles...

Answer (score 0):

In Mac OsX Sonoma 14.1.1 the location is

```
/System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/Resources/Initial\ Settings/
```

HTH

Comment: That's the initial defaults, not the per-user profiles.